# Why the Element D don't put down the element B, and C

Tags: css, layout

Here is the page I render:

[image]

Here is the source code:

> ```
> <div id="a">
> </div>
> </div id="b">
> </div>
> <div id="c">
> </div>
> <div id="d">about
> </div>
> ```

also CSS file:

```
#a{
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center; 
  height:120px;
  background-color:green;
}   

#b{
  background-image:url('resources/weneedu.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center; 
  width:40%; 
  height:340px;
  position:absolute;
  left:10% 
}   

#c{
  background-image:url('resources/yunoguy.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center; 
  width:40%; 
  height:340px;
  position:absolute;
  left:52%;
}
```

Why the element D move under the element A, and left to the element B? like this, interestingly, it move before, C, and B:
[image]

Also, if I would like to do something like this: How to achieve it? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: To answer the question in the title: because you're using absolute positioning.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL is correct on the first part of your post.  Since you are absolutely positioning elements b and c... element d isn't affected by their spacing.

Answer (score 2):

`position: absolute`removes elements out of their natural flow. Try using `position: relative` instead and see if this gets you where you want.

Why not positioning #d the same way?